# How to create Sass mixin aliases with support for content blocks?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

How can I define multiple names for the same mixin, with support for content blocks?

**Definition**

```
@mixin desktop-breakpoint {
   @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
      @content;
   }
}

@mixin large-breakpoint {
   @include desktop-breakpoint;
}
```

**Usage**

```
.my-class {
   font-size: small;

   @include desktop-breakpoint {
      font-size: big;
   }
}

.my-other-class {
   color: red;

   @include large-breakpoint {
      color: blue;
   }
}
```

**Error message**

> Mixin "large-breakpoint" does not accept a content block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not passing any `@content` when using `@include desktop-breakpoint` in your `large-breakpoint` mixin. Doing this will fix your compilation error:

```
@mixin large-breakpoint {
   // Remember to pass content received by mixin to @include
   @include desktop-breakpoint {
     @content;
   }
}
```

Then your CSS will be compiled properly, as intended:

```
.my-class {
  font-size: small;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .my-class {
    font-size: big;
  }
}

.my-other-class {
  color: red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .my-other-class {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

See proof-of-concept example based on your modified code: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3109af060293eed0b89a22c27fa20527